# Company Branding from Microsoft Graph: Azure B2C

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We want to set company branding for our B2C tenant. We are able to achieve that from Portal but our usecase is to do it programmatically that too Microsoft Graph.

We have Organization.ReadWrite.All permission that allows us to read and write organization information.

Found this to do company branding from Microsoft Graph:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization/tID/branding

{
    "backgroundColor" : ""
}
```

How to set logo or background image from Microsoft Graph? Any idea

Comment: see this page, although the example is for a GET, the left menu, there is a link label Update, it may just be what you're looking for (provided you've not already seen it), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationalbranding-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: It depends on the language you want to use.